# How to change the type of camera in Three.js?

Tags: javascript, webgl, three.js

I provided a dropdown list for two cameras (Perspective and Orthographic) on the page. Right now my Three Scene is using perspective Camera. But based on the selection in dropdown list, my camera should be changed to "Orthographic" and turns to Perspective If I select Perspective in the dropdown list. How could I achieve this? Please help me.

For detail code, Here is Jsfiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/sagh0900/7Anag/9/

```
camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 45, width / height, 0.1, 1000 );
camera.position.y = 0;
camera.position.z = 40;
camera.lookAt(new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 0));  
scene = new THREE.Scene();
scene.add(camera);
mesh = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.Geometry());
scene.add(mesh);
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you please update the jsfiddle with the changes suggested by ditkin.-@webGLnoobie

Comment: That was the whole point here, I could able to update the changes in my eclipse environment. but Jsfiddle is not working in the same way. I also added "CombinedCamera.js" to additional resources but still not working :(, Jsfiddle Link: jsfiddle.net/sagh0900/7Anag/24

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had suggested using CombinedCamera.  It no longer exists.  You can use what @prisoner849 has suggested in this post [Three JS, Combined camera Documentation and support](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47072699/three-js-combined-camera-documentation-and-support)

> You can use a variable, which you will assign one camera or another
>   to. – prisoner849

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I'm able to see the change in my eclipse environment but where are JSfiddle environment isn't working. I've added CombinedCamera.js as "Additional Resource" in Jsfiddle, but still couldn't see the output. Could you please check with that.
My jsfiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/sagh0900/7Anag/24/

Answer (score 4):

I don't think you can change the Camera type of a camera instance on the fly, as they are separate classes and need to be instantiated separately.

You can however create two camera instances, one Ortographic and one Perspective camera, and specify on your render() call which camera is active. You would need to update both camera's position etc on your UI event handlers, or alternatively, clone the position etc in the render function.

Looking at three.js source though, it looks like it wouldn't be too hard to hack together a custom camera class that supports orto/perspective mode switching... That would be kind of a hack though.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, Mr.ditkin solution helped me. but could you place a jsfiddle link of your thought since I couldn't understand what you are meaning exactly.