# Three JS, Combined camera Documentation and support

Tags: three.js, camera

Is the **Combined Camera** in Three Js depricated in the recent release or is it an issue? Because I am unable to see its documentaion which was supposed to be [here](https://threejs.org/docs/examples/cameras/CombinedCamera.html). But the page is not available now. Also the example for the same is supposed to be [here](https://threejs.org/examples/canvas_camera_orthographic2.html). It is also not available now. I have gone through the recent release versions and js files related to Combined Camera are missing in [r88](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/tree/r88)(latest release).Can someone suggest if I can use the **Combined Camera** or any other alternative to switch between Orthographic and perspective camera.

Comment: You can use a variable, which you will assign one camera or another to.

Comment: I had problems with `CombinedCamera` as far back as r67. I do what @prisoner849 recommended. I have three `vars`: `camera`, `pCamera`, and `oCamera`. I assign the value of `camera` to be `pCamera` or `oCamera` as appropriate, and only pass `camera` into `WebGLRenderer.render`.

Comment: Thanks @prisoner849 We are doing the same now, but Combined Camera was easy to use. Not sure why it is depricated.